# Freezing on start up after fresh install

Tags: system-installation, startup, freeze

I downloaded ubuntu and used the Universal USB creator/installer from pendrivelinux.com. I have a dedicated hard drive for this install so it seems installation can not get anymore simpler. After installing and restarting the computer ubuntu freezes on a start screen with the ubuntu logo in the middle, a dotted grid and the version number in the lower left hand corner and just sits there. What could possibly have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the 64bit Ubuntu won't boot from a USB, you need to use the 32bit installer. Also you miight try at boot, press the F6 key and unselect the options.

[How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. For some reason, in some way, it has miraculously worked. 64 bit, installed from a USB. I wish  I knew more but around the 5th try it worked. Thanks again!